# I'm having trouble getting this to export military time

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-timestamp

Can you tell me how to modify the date/time format to give me military time?

I'm Los Angeles time which is GMT-08:00

It's giving me 07:28 but what I want is 19:28.

Answer (score 1):

Reread the post and found the answer here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates

Changed `MM/dd/yy, hh:mm:ss` to `MM/dd/yy, HH:mm:ss`

Best!